# Nesting IF AND OR functions in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to create a new column in my dataset that will display a "yes" if ANY of the three criteria are met in two different columns and a "no" if none of the criteria are met.

For example if someone participated in year 1 and scored a 2 or above on either of two assessments OR participated in year 2 and scored a 2.5 or above on either of two assessments OR participated in year 3 and scored a 3 or above on either of two assessments I want the cell to read "Yes" because that person met the benchmark. They only need to meet one in either column to display "Yes" not all three. If they meet none it should display "No" because they didn't meet the benchmark for their year.

Here is the last iteration of what I've tried. This works, but only compares in ONE column (M2) and I need it to compare in M2 and V2.

```
=IF(AND(B2="Year 1",M2>=2),"Yes",IF(AND(B2="Year 2",M2>=2.5),"Yes",IF(AND(B2="Year 3",M2>=3),"Yes","No")))
```

Here's what I'm currently tinkering with:

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2="Year 1",M2>=2,B2="Year 1",V2>=2)),"Yes",IF(AND(OR(B2="Year 2",M2>=2.5,B2="Year 2",V2>=2.5)),"Yes",IF(AND(OR(B2="Year 3",M2>=3,B2="Year 3",V2>=3))"Yes","No")))
```

I feel like I'm close, but it's so hard to search for help about "if" because it's such a common word.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Dara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2="Year 1", OR(M2>=2, V2>=2)),
       AND(B2="Year 2", OR(M2>=2.5, V2>=2.5)),
       AND(B2="Year 3", OR(M2>=3, V2>=3))),
    "Yes",
    "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is critical, you can use this link to build it properly.
http://www.qlikblog.at/tools/Nested-If-Generator.html